# External PHP File

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that will be used on many webpages, so I want to use an external file for PHP rather than adding the PHP to each HTML page. I have one question:

How can I make it so when the "submit" button in an HTML form is clicked, a function (or the whole code) from an external PHP file will run?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="your_php_file.php" method="post">
    .. your stuff ..
</form>
```

Comment: So does your_php_file.php need to be in function format or no? Just plain PHP?

Comment: Actually nevermind stupid question of course not. But do you still need <?php ?> even if the file extension specifies it is PHP?

Comment: In the PHP file you do, in the HTML file where the form is, no.